# How can I multiply two matrices in C#?

Tags: c#, math

Like described in the title, is there some library in the Microsoft framework which allows to multiply two matrices or do I have to write my own method to do this? // I've got an answer to this by now

Second question:
I wrote this multi class with a MultiplyMatrix method but it doesn't work like I want to. Can anyone help and tell where I made a mistake?

```
class multi
    {
        public void MultiplyMatrix(double[,] _A, double[,] _B, int _n, int _m, int _r)
        {
            int n, m, r;
            double si;
            n = _n;
            m = _m;
            r = _r;
            double[,] A = new double[n, m];
            double[,] B = new double[m, r];
            double[,] C = new double[n, r];
            A = _A;
            B = _B;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
                    {
                        si = 0;
                        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                        {
                            si += A[i, m + k] + B[k, r + j];
                        }
                        C[i, r + j] = si;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < C.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < C.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(C[i, j]+" ");
                        if (j % 3 == 0)
                            Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { } // I always get this exception

        }

    }
```

I forgot to tell: I want to make a webservice to multiply on it.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built into .NET. You will have to write the multiplication yourself or use some third party library. I've [blogged](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/48-fun-with-matrix-multiplication-and-unsafe-code.html) about one way to achieve this comparing two different implementations : a standard naive algorithm and one using unsafe code.

Answer (score 16):

Multiplication of 2 matrixes:

```
    public double[,] MultiplyMatrix(double[,] A, double[,] B)
    {
        int rA = A.GetLength(0);
        int cA = A.GetLength(1);
        int rB = B.GetLength(0);
        int cB = B.GetLength(1);

        if (cA != rB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Matrixes can't be multiplied!!");
        }
        else
        {
            double temp = 0;
            double[,] kHasil = new double[rA, cB];

            for (int i = 0; i < rA; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cB; j++)
                {
                    temp = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < cA; k++)
                    {
                        temp += A[i, k] * B[k, j];
                    }
                    kHasil[i, j] = temp;
                }
            }

            return kHasil;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is working example. I would only suggest using jugged matrix implmentation for better performance.

Answer (score 14):

Whilst there's no built in Maths framework to do this in .NET (could use XNA's Maths library), there is a `Matrix` in the [System.Windows.Media](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635216.aspx) namespace. The Matrix structure has a [Multiply method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.multiply.aspx) which takes in another Matrix and outputs a Matrix.

```
Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12);

// matrixResult is equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
Matrix matrixResult = Matrix.Multiply(matrix1, matrix2);

// matrixResult2 is also
// equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
Matrix matrixResult2 = matrix1 * matrix2;
```

This is mainly used for 2D transformation:

> Represents a 3x3 affine transformation
>   matrix used for transformations in 2-D
>   space.

but if it suits your needs, then there's no need for any third party libraries.

Comment: Also `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix` in plain old WinForms.

Answer (score 11):

Although you can multiply matrices by an iterative approach (for loops), performing the calculations with linear algebra will clean up your code and will give you performance gains that are several times faster!

There is a free library available in nuget - **MathNet.Numerics**. It makes it extremely easy to multiply matrices:

```
Matrix<double> a = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } });
Matrix<double> b = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } });
Matrix<double> result = a * b;
```

It has no dependencies and can be used in .net core 2.0, making it an excellent choice to *avoid iterative matrix multiplication techniques and take advantage of linear algebra*.

Answer (score 3):

CSML - C# Matrix Library - is a compact and lightweight package for numerical linear algebra. Many matrix operations known from Matlab, Scilab and Co. are implemented.
See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSML.aspx)!

Answer (score 1):

There are no such built in libraries. Unless you are using [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203940.aspx) - it has a [`Matrix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix_members.aspx) class, though it is limited and designed for 3D games.

There are [many](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/AdvancedMatrixLibrary.aspx) [matrix](http://www.bluebit.gr/net/) [libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/psdotnetmatrix.aspx) for .NET though.

Comment: XNA not required, WinForms has System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace matrix_multiplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, j;
            int[,] a = new int[2, 2];
            Console.WriteLine("Enter no for 2*2 matrix");
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    a[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("First matrix is:");
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                  Console.Write(a[i,j]+"\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(); 
            }


            int[,] b = new int[2, 2];
            Console.WriteLine("Enter no for 2*2 matrix");
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    b[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("second matrix is:");
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(b[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Matrix multiplication is:");
            int[,] c = new int[2, 2];
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {


                    c[i,j]=0;
                     for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                     {
                         c[i, j] +=  a[i, k] * b[k, j];
                     }
                 }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(c[i, j]+"\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

output

Enter no for 2*2 matrix

```
8
7
6
0
```

First matrix is:

```
8       7
6       0
```

Enter no for 2*2 matrix

```
4
3
2
1
```

second matrix is:

```
4       3
2       1
```

Matrix multiplication is:

```
46      31
24      18
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the method to multiply int[3,4] matrix with int[4,3] matrix, it has time complexity of O(n cube) or Cubic time

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        MultiplyMatrix();
    }

    static void MultiplyMatrix()
    {
        int[,] metrix1 = new int[3,4] { { 1, 2,3,2 }, { 3, 4,5,6 }, { 5, 6,8,4 } };
        int[,] metrix2 = new int[4, 3] { { 2, 5, 3 }, { 4, 5, 1 }, { 8, 7, 9 }, { 3, 7, 2 } };
        int[,] metrixMultplied = new int[3, 3];

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            { 
                for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                {
                    metrixMultplied[row, col] = metrixMultplied[row, col] + metrix1[row, i] * metrix2[i, col];

                }
                Console.Write(metrixMultplied[row, col] + ", ");                   
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code : 4*4 matrix

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{        
    int column = 0;
    while (column < 4)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            matrixResult[i, column] += Convert.ToInt32(matrixR[i, j] * matrixT[count, column]);
            count = count + 1;
        }
        column = column + 1;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you have a helper to generate, iterate and populate an `int[,]` matrix like this one:

```cs
public class VisitMatrix{
    public static int[,] execute(int rows, int columns, Func<int, int, int> fn)
    {
        int[,] result = new int[rows, columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                result[i, j] = fn(i, j);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now matrix multiplication is as trivial as doing (supposing `m1.GetLength(1) == m2.GetLength(0)`):

```cs
public class MultiplyMatrices{
    public static int[,] execute(int[,] m1, int[,] m2, int modulus = 10)
    {
        return VisitMatrix.execute(m1.GetLength(0), m2.GetLength(1), (i, j) =>
            Enumerable.Range(0, m1.GetLength(1)-1)
                .Select(k => m1[i, k] * m2[k, j])
                .Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + b, e => e % modulus)
    }
}
```