# How to calculate matrix multiplication in language C

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I tried this code but something is wrong

```
        for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col2; j++)
            suma = 0;
            for (l = 0; l < row2; l++)
            suma += a[i][l] * bt[l][j];
            c[i][j] = suma;             
    }
    printf("\nMultiplication of 2 matrices:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col2; j++)
            printf("%2d", c[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

when i debug it it prints out random numbers in both rows and columns (something like -895473 )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311309/how-can-i-multiply-two-matrices-in-c

Answer (score 5):

Missing braces.

```
for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < col2; j++) { // added brace
        suma = 0;
        for (l = 0; l < row2; l++) { // added brace
            suma += a[i][l] * bt[l][j];
        } // added brace
        c[i][j] = suma;             
    } // added brace
}
```

The braces on the inside aren't *strictly necessary* but if you always use braces you are less likely to make this particular mistake in the future.

Without the braces, it looks like this, correctly indented:

```
for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < col2; j++)
        suma = 0;
    // Note that j = col2, which means that we are accessing
    // array elements out of bounds, which is an error.
    for (l = 0; l < row2; l++)
        suma += a[i][l] * bt[l][j];
    c[i][j] = suma;             
}
```

This is more obviously wrong.  Another way to make the error less likely is to move the variables inside the loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
        double suma = 0;
        for (int l = 0; l < row2; l++) {
            suma += a[i][l] * bt[l][j];
        }
        c[i][j] = suma;             
    }
}
```

This way, if you remove the braces, you will get an error because `j` is not defined.  (This doesn't work in C90, but that's ancient history these days.)

Comment: Here is my entire code:   *https://ideone.com/pdBf8K* . I would appreciate if you could tell me what i did wrong.