# Efficient way to Flip a 2D Array Horizontally or Vertically

Tags: c#

The problem is to make a program the flips a 2D (2 by 2) array either horizontally(H) or vertically(V), depending on the input the user puts. For example, if the user puts "HHHVVHVHV", it means to flip 5 times horizontally, and 4 times vertically. The code I attached below works, but I am not sure if there is a built-in method in C# to flip arrays or an easier way to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace _2019JuniorQ4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Varables
            int[,] grid = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
            int[,] flippedGrid = new int[2, 2];
            string input = "";
            int h = 0;
            int v = 0;
            int flipHorizontal = 0;
            int flipVertical = 0;
            //Input
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            //Count number of times
            for (int i=0; i<input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (input[i] == Convert.ToChar("H"))
                {
                    h++;
                }
                else if(input[i] == Convert.ToChar("V"))
                {
                    v++;
                }
            }
            //Process
            flipHorizontal = h % 2;
            flipVertical = v % 2;
            //Vertical flip
            if (flipVertical == 1)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 1; x >= 0; x--)
                    {
                        flippedGrid[y, Math.Abs(x - 1)] = grid[y,x];
                    }
                }
                grid = flippedGrid.Clone() as int[,];
            }
            //Horizontal Flip
            if (flipHorizontal == 1)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 1; y >= 0; y--)
                    {
                        flippedGrid[Math.Abs(y - 1), x] = grid[y,x];
                    }
                }
                grid = flippedGrid.Clone() as int[,];
            }
            //Output
            for (int x=0; x<2; x++)
            {
                for (int y=0; y<2; y++)
                {
                    Console.Write(grid[x,y]+" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With a 2 by 2 array you could just hard code the 4 possible results.

Comment: But what if the user enters a bunch of input like VHVHVHVHVHHHHVHVHVHVHVHHVHVHVHVVH...

Comment: Your code already handles that by determining if there are an even or odd number of vertical and horizontal flips.  Then the result is either the same as the original; vertically flipped; horizontally flipped; or both.  You just hard code those 4 possible results instead of actually manipulating the array.

Comment: Code wise.... efficient would be a matrix multiplication. You can specify 1 multiplication function and use a flip-horizontal, flip-vertical ... or even more of those as multiplier....

Comment: A very simple implementation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311309/how-can-i-multiply-two-matrices-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I multiply two matrices in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311309/how-can-i-multiply-two-matrices-in-c)