# Multithreading and get X sub matrixes

Tags: c#, multithreading, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get into multithreading by trying to do matrix multiplication and my problem is, how I would get all sub matrixes from a matrix.

My matrix variable is a `int[,]`.

Example, if I have a matrix by 100 x 100, how would i get 10 of 10 x 10 sub matrix. And is it possible that user can choose to how many equal parts to cut up the matrix even if I the matrix is not a square ex. 400 x 300?

Is it even the right way to do it, by calculate on the sub matrixes and then add them together when done?

Comment: Since matrix multiplication is a combination of multiplication and addition, you could do the multiplications in parallel and then add the results in a final step, I suppose.

Comment: Okay that was somewhat what i was thinking to be the best solution from what i understand. Do you know any good read about parallel multithreading? Do you have an idea to how i would make the sub matrixes? And is it better to make smallest possible sub matrixes and have a lot of them to do parallel threading?

Comment: You should use existing tools like the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl), if possible, which saves you a lot of work and mistakes. Also, whenever it comes to multithreading, I always recommend a functional approach (mainly immutability + pure functions), since it's naturally thread-safe. As for which approach is best ... profile! I recommend BenchmarkDotNet. You might be surprised, sometimes a non-parallel approach is faster even, due to less overhead.

Comment: And remember: Google is your friend https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/matrix-multiplication-in-parallel-with-c-and-the-tpl/

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with multithreading

Comment: @Charlieface while the question in itself is not a pure multithreading question becauseits more focused on the sub matrixes, im still asking an (open) question to how i would calculate the sub matrixes on different threads, parallal or etc. If you read the beginning i said im trying to get into multithreading by choosing a project where there is a lot of big calculations => good place to start multithreading, and i asked about multithreading so i could read what people have done, worked with or will recommend to do so as other have done.

Comment: @marsze those 2 links look interesting and what i think my end goal will be. Thanks! I have scouted the web the last 2 days, but was starting to get drained reading about it, so i thought i wanted to hear peoples solutions :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would i get 10 of 10 x 10 sub matrix

You would do a double loop, copying each value from the original matrix to the new sub matrix.

> Is it even the right way to do it, by calculate on the sub matrixs and then add them together when done?

The normal way to multiply matrices is with a triple loop, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20800090/12342238). It should be fairly trivial to convert the outer loop to a parallel.For loop, since all calculations are independent from each other. This avoids any need to process individual sub matrices, and let the framework deal with partitioning the work.

However, things like this is typically fairly cache sensitive. A matrix will be stored in memory as sequential values, either row or column major. Accessing sequential values will be very cache friendly, but accessing non sequential values will not be. So you might want to copy a full row/column to a temporary array to ensure all subsequent accesses are sequential. If using a parallel loop you should probably use one of the overloads that give you a thread local array to use. There more things one can do with cache optimizations, and SIMD intrinstics but that is probably best left as a later exercise.

There are algorithms with a lower algorithmic complexity that does work on submatrices, but in my experience it will be fairly tricky to make this actually faster in c# than a cache-optimized triple loop.

Keep in mind to measure the performance of your method. I would also suggest comparing your performance with some well optimized existing library to get some sense of how performant your implementation is.