# Matrix Multiplication Cache Issue

Tags: c#, optimization, deep-learning, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

I have a little neural network program. I have optimized it to train quicker, but I have noticed that the backpropagation part takes around 10 times longer than the forward pass. I of course saw that the only major difference is that I am accessing my weight matrix non sequentially (as opposed to sequentially, like in the forward pass). This leads to cache misses and messes up my performance. On the forward pass, I loop trough all neurons in the current layer, then trough all input neurons, and I access the weights of the current layer in the order they are laid out in the matrix. The matrix holds the weights for the current neuron on rows. As such, I am iterating for every input neuron, so I am iterating over the columns, and as such, in a cache friendly way. On the backward pass, however, I am looping trough the neurons of the current layer, then trough the neurons of the next (output or hidden) layer. I then access the weights of that next layer, and access individual elements from the rows, inside my loop. This makes my index jump over entire rows in the matrix, effectively destroying my cache performance. Is there a way to do this backwards step in a more cache friendly way?

Comment: I think you're assuming to much background for your question. Can you elaborate a bit on the details of what you're doing?

Comment: I am multiplying 2 matrices. In one pass, I access the elements of the matrices in a cache friendly way, but in the other one, I am not. I want to know how I can improve the access order so that I don't lose that much performance. In the second pass, I loop over the rows of the matrix, but my elements are laid out in sequence (over the columns). In the first pass, I loop over the columns.

Comment: Ok, got it. Since you talk about neural networks, I'm assuming those matrices are huge?

Comment: Very. That is why streaming the data into the CPU is expensive. It slows down 10x because of the cache misses.

Comment: I think I am on the right track.

Comment: I think it works. I basically now loop trough the next layer's neurons, then the current layer's neurons, and I can access the weights inside this inner loop in the cache friendly fashion. The change is that I now sum up the gradients inside an array which I index in the inner loop. Thing is, this backwards phase is now 4x faster then the OTHER, fast steps, which leads me to believe I made some kind of mistake. But I am running the network, and it is producing good results. Quite a mystery I have here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in neural networks, but I have spent a little bit of time with matrix multiplication.

A very simple and effective optimization when multiplying matrices is to read a complete row (assuming column major matrix) and store this in a temporary array to be reused. Modifying this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20800090/12342238) slightly:

```
var arr = new double[cA];

for (int j = 0; j<cB; j++)

{
    for(int t = 0; t < cA; t++){
        arr[t] = B[t, j]
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i<rA; i++)
    {
        temp = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k<cA; k++)
        {
            temp += A[i, k] * arr[k];
        }
        result[i, j] = temp;
    }
}
```

The point is to copy in the slow direction in the outer loop, so these values can be reused each time in the inner loop. This is fairly simple, and helps a great deal with cache efficiency.

An even better approach would be to read an entire cache-lines and reuse these values as much as possible, but that requires like 6 nested loops, so you will need to find other resources for an exact description on how to do it, I would not be confident writing one freehand.

Some other tips:

1. Just use a library, there should be plenty of well optimized matrix multiplication implementation out there.
2. If you use multidimensional matrices, make sure to not call `.GetLength()` repeatedly, this is super slow.
3. Consider making your own matrix class that uses a 1D array as the backing storage. This may help reduce index calculations a bit, but the greatest benefit is ease of interoperability. External tools and libraries have spotty support for multidimensional matrices. 1D matrices are usually better supported.
4. Use [SIMD intrinstics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/), this should give a ~4 times speedup
5. Use a parallel outer loop